# Outputting an array with FirePHP

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, firephp

How do you output an array with FirePHP?

I'm using FirePHP in a Zend Framework project. I can output the value of individual variables with:

```
$logger->log('foo = '.$foo, Zend_Log::INFO);
```

and see something like:

```
foo = "Ponies!"
```

However if $foo is an array I only see:

```
foo = Array
```

and the word `Array` is not clickable or hoverable or anything.

I googled Google and my googling didn't return anything about how to output the values in an array with FirePHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't have much to do with FirePHP, it's because you're concatenating the array to a string: `'foo = '.$foo`. At this point PHP has to cast the array to a string, [which results in the string "`Array`"](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting). If you'd just do `$logger->log($foo)`, the array would probably be expanded automatically (depending on how intelligent the logger class is, most do this kind of thing).

If you need to expand the array manually, use [`var_export($foo, true)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php).

Comment: And that did it. I didn't even consider that concatenating the array to a string would cast it as such. Makes sense but I just glossed right over that, mentally. Thanks!

Comment: FirePHP also supports special formatters.  Check out the "Setting Styles" section on the docs page; http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.log.writers.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use implode function which provide the way join array to string

```
$arr_str = implode(',', $arr);
$this->firephp->log($arr_str);
```

firephp is just a logger, which trace output is not it's point